# Replace each row in a list with another data in r

Tags: r, replace

I want to replace last rows (called "h24") of all elements in a list (org) with another list (ch) which its each elements contain single value. Data structures were given at the end. Also I need to keep "h24" as row name.

Here is my original data (org);

```
$`01-2020`
    [,1]
m5    NA
m10   NA
m15   NA
m30   NA
h1    NA
h2    NA
h3    NA
h4    NA
h5    NA
h6    NA
h8    NA
h12   NA
h18   NA
h24   NA

$`01-2021`
      [,1]
m5   0.910
m10  1.819
m15  2.729
m30  5.401
h1  10.150
h2  20.300
h3  30.450
h4  31.935
h5  42.085
h6  40.242
h8  41.083
h12 54.158
h18 84.400
h24 87.586

$`01-2022`
      [,1]
m5   0.680
m10  1.360
m15  2.029
m30  3.862
h1   6.501
h2  13.002
h3  16.452
h4  18.895
h5  22.970
h6  27.564
h8  37.271
h12 30.600
h18 52.338
h24 55.374
```

data to replace

```
$`01-2020`
[1] 103.03

$`01-2021`
[1] 99

$`01-2022`
[1] 87
```

***Desired output***

```
$`01-2020`
        [,1]
    m5    NA
    m10   NA
    m15   NA
    m30   NA
    h1    NA
    h2    NA
    h3    NA
    h4    NA
    h5    NA
    h6    NA
    h8    NA
    h12   NA
    h18   NA
    h24   103.03
    
    $`01-2021`
          [,1]
    m5   0.910
    m10  1.819
    m15  2.729
    m30  5.401
    h1  10.150
    h2  20.300
    h3  30.450
    h4  31.935
    h5  42.085
    h6  40.242
    h8  41.083
    h12 54.158
    h18 84.400
    h24 99
    
    $`01-2022`
          [,1]
    m5   0.680
    m10  1.360
    m15  2.029
    m30  3.862
    h1   6.501
    h2  13.002
    h3  16.452
    h4  18.895
    h5  22.970
    h6  27.564
    h8  37.271
    h12 30.600
    h18 52.338
    h24 87
```

**Data structures**

1. original data

   ```
   org<-list(`01-2020` = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
            NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
            NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), .Dim = c(14L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
                c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", 
                "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)), `01-2021` = structure(c(0.91, 
            1.819, 2.729, 5.401, 10.15, 20.3, 30.45, 31.935, 42.085, 40.242, 
            41.083, 54.158, 84.4, 87.586), .Dim = c(14L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
                c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", 
                "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)), `01-2022` = structure(c(0.68, 
            1.36, 2.029, 3.862, 6.501, 13.002, 16.452, 18.895, 22.97, 27.564, 
            37.271, 30.6, 52.338, 55.374), .Dim = c(14L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
                c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", 
                "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)))
   ```

data to replace

```
ch<-list(`01-2020` = 103.03, `01-2021` = 87.58, `01-2022` = 55.37)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop over the corresponding elements of both `list` and `replace` the last row (`nrow`) with the element of 'ch'

```
org1 <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, nrow(x), y), org, ch[names(org)])
```

If it is to replace only when it is a missing value

```
org1 <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, seq_len(nrow(x)) == nrow(x) & 
        is.na(x), y), org, ch[names(org)])
```

Comment: I believe it will be good to use reorder the lists to match the naming in case they are not in the same order. Though this is still a good Base Roption